# How can I use a glob to ignore files that start with an underscore?

Tags: gulp, glob

I am using this file matching in gulp:

```
'content/css/*.css'
```

But I would like to only include the files that **do not** start with an underscore. Can someone tell me how I can do this?

Here's the code:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src('content/less/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('content/css'));
});
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a regexp, it looks like a filename wildcard.

Comment: I think it is referred to as a glob in gulp but I am a bit confused by it all.

Comment: That's what it's called in the shell, too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If Gulp wildcards are like shell wildcards:

```
content/css/[^_]*.css
```

The `^` at the beginning of a character set means to match any characters **not** in the set.

Answer (score 8):

You can add a second glob whitch will filter files or folders with an underscore.

For ignore folders I use:

```
gulp.src(['./src/**/*.html', '!**/_*/**'])
```

`'!**/_*/**'` will filter folders that start with an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Use this plugin https://github.com/robrich/gulp-ignore

```
var gulpIgnore = require('gulp-ignore');
var condition = '_*.css'; //exclude condition

gulp.task('less', function() {
  gulp.src('content/less/*.less')
    .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(condition))
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/'));
});
```

I think gulp supports file **glob not full-regex**, But You can give a try to `content/css/[^_]*.less`

Comment: I'm very open to your new suggestiong but can you check my updated question where I show the code that's being used. I think my version might be a bit simpler as it does not need gulp-ignore. I welcome your comments on this. Thanks

Comment: Check the updated post, 
But your code is including all the files ending with .less
I am not sure if gulp by default supports full regex in filenames!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regex.

```
content/css/[^_].*\.css
```

Add `$` at the last if necessary.

Comment: Can you tell me what the ".*\" in the middle does here? Also I am looking for files that do not start with an underscore.

Comment: `[^_]` matches the first letter of the filename, only if it's not an underscore. So the following `.*` matches any character non-greedily, it matches underscores also. And the final `.css` asserts that the filenames must end with .css`

Answer (score 1):

For those using Python (coming from Google like me), the correct would be:

```py
import glob
glob.glob('content/css/[!_]*.css')
```