# How to detect root files in LESS using gulp compilation

Tags: css, less, gulp, gulp-less

Here is the thing. I have following structure of my LESS files:

```
/less/root.less
/less/includes1/*.less (a lot of less files)
/less/includes2/*.less (a lot of less files)
```

I am using gulp to compile my LESS files. Source:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    var combined = combiner.obj([
    gulp.src('./less/**/*.less'),
    less(),
    gulp.dest('./www/dist/screen.css')
]);

// any errors in the above streams will get caught by this listener, instead of being thrown:
combined.on('error', console.error.bind(console));

return combined;
});
```

The problem is in the specified path. I understand this path `./less/**/*.less` like this: Recursively go through all folders and compile all files that ends `.less`. Problem is that compiler wants to compile each file one by one and doesnt know that all files are included to my `source.less`. It doesnt look for root files and doesnt know what files are included parts and what are root files.

How do I tell LESS parser which files are root and which files are to be imported. In SASS it is specified via underscore in file name like this: _includedPart.scss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use https://github.com/robrich/gulp-ignore. See: [How can I use a glob to ignore files that start with an underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689351/how-can-i-use-a-regex-to-ignore-files-that-start-with-an-underscore)

```
  var condition = '_*.less'; //exclude condition
  gulp.src('content/**/*.less')
    .pipe(gulpIgnore.exclude(condition))
```

In many situations you all your Less code into a single CSS file. Your main file(s) contain `@import` directive which point all other required Less files.

Comment: Thank you! I though this is possible to do more "natural LESS way" but I guess not.