# Why is Prepros compiling scss files prefixed with underscore?

Tags: sass, preprocessor, prepros

I've generated a couple of helper scss files within my scss project folder indicated by a '_' prefix. On file change however, prepros will compile them into a css file.

As I understand how this should work is _ should indicate to the pre-processor to ignore the file until explicitly included into a standard .scss file. And this isn't the case. Would this be a bug in prepros or is there a configuration setting somewhere that I would need to adjust?

Comment: I don't know about prepos, but usually you need to manually specify which files you'd like to ignore. About ignoring files that start with underscore https://stackoverflow.com/a/27689389/4877989

Comment: After you add the files to your project, refresh the project in Prepos before you save it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but what's happening is if the partials are imported into a main SCSS file, the compiler will ignore the partials as individual files and include them in the main CSS output. If they are not imported, they will compile unless you filter them in the software.

Answer (score 1):

I used **Prepros** a lot,

*I have two Solution of this.*

**Solution 1:** It may be a bug a in software, So updating may solve your problem.

**Solution 2:** You may have not configured settings, So updating configuration settings.

**To updating configuration settings do the following steps:**
**1**- Click on settings
[image]  
**2**- Now In **File Watcher** panel, go to **Path Filters** and add `_*.scss` in it. Now what this will do is that it will ignore all .scss extension files starting with `_` containg any name.  
[image]
:)